# delete pointer after return value

Tags: c++, pointers

hello I have the following functions:

```
Block* Keywords::parseBlock(TiXmlElement* element)
{
    double x1 = atoi(element->Attribute("left"));
    double y1 = atoi(element->Attribute("top"));
    double x2 = atoi(element->Attribute("right"));
    double y2 = atoi(element->Attribute("bottom"));
    double width  = abs(x2 - x1);
    int bid = atoi(element->Attribute("id"));

    vector<LineElement*> lines;
    for (TiXmlElement* sub = element->FirstChildElement("line"); sub; sub = sub->NextSiblingElement("line"))
        lines.push_back(parseLine(sub));

    return new Block(y2,x2,y1,x1,bid,width, lines);
}///End function parse Block

LineElement* Keywords::parseLine(TiXmlElement* element)
{
    double x1 = atoi(element->Attribute("left"));
    double y1 = atof(element->Attribute("top"));
    double x2 = atoi(element->Attribute("right"));
    double y2 =  atoi(element->Attribute("bottom"));
    int bid = atoi(element->Attribute("id"));

    vector<Element*> words;
    for (TiXmlElement* sub = element->FirstChildElement("word"); sub; sub = sub->NextSiblingElement("word"))
        words.push_back(parseWord(sub));

    return new LineElement(y2,x2,y1,x1,bid,words);
}///End function parse Line

Element * Keywords::parseWord(TiXmlElement* element)
{
    string w =element->Attribute("value");
    double x1 = atoi(element->Attribute("left"));
    double y1 = atoi(element->Attribute("top"));
    double x2 = atoi(element->Attribute("right"));
    double y2 = atoi(element->Attribute("bottom"));
    int bid = atoi(element->Attribute("id"));

    vector<Letter*> chars;

    for (TiXmlElement* sub = element->FirstChildElement("char"); sub; sub = sub->NextSiblingElement("char"))
        chars.push_back(parseChar(sub));

    return new  Element(w,y1, x1, y2,x2,-1,bid,chars);
}///End function parse word

Letter * Keywords::parseChar(TiXmlElement* element)
{
    string w = element->Attribute("value");
    double x1 = atoi(element->Attribute("left"));
    double y1 = atoi(element->Attribute("top"));
    double x2 = atoi(element->Attribute("right"));
    double y2 =  atoi(element->Attribute("bottom"));
    int bid = atoi(element->Attribute("id"));
    return new Letter(w,y1,x1,y2,x2,bid);
}
```

I think that I have a memory leak, How can I delete the pointer after returning it? 
How can I use the destructor to free the memory I am getting a Run-Time error bad:alloc

Comment: @vidit No i didn't the error is : Terminate call after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'

Comment: Run this through a debugger like `gdb` so you can figure out where it crashed.

Comment: Registered new type: wxString
Registered new type: STL String
Registered new type: STL Vector
Setting breakpoints
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5
Child process PID: 6316
Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
In ntdll!TpWaitForAlpcCompletion () (C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll)
#15 0x0043d519 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate (this=0x28f684, __p=0xa90460) at c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h:98
c:include\c++\ext\new_allocator.h:98:3034:beg:0x43d519
At c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\ext\new_allocator.h:98

Comment: That's a bit of a mess. Look into boosts Smart Pointers: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm

Comment: Looks like you're deferring ownership of the instance pointers to the caller of your `Keywords::parseLine()`, etc. methods. The caller is responsible for deleting these instances. I'd recommend to use any of the standard smart pointer classes for this (at least `std::auto_ptr`) instead of returning naked pointers.

Comment: Include the debugger output in the question so it can be formatted correctly.

Comment: Why are you returning pointers anyway?

Comment: I'd scrap this whole nightmare and write actual C++ code not a java transcript. If you just collect and return objects instead of pointers, your issues will be gone too.

Comment: @BrendanLong What to argue about debug output, the given code shows no `delete`statement anyway, and I'd bet it's a basic misunderstanding how to work with heap allocated instances.

Comment: 1) What makes you think you have a memory leak? A memory leak will not cause a run-time error. 2) It's easy enough to use `delete`, just look it up; it will invoke the relevant destructor. 3) If you want us to help you with the error, please give us a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Beta Looks like the calling methods simply don't track the returned instances correctly ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this, like @BalogPal said, is to stop treating C++ like Java. There's no reason to return pointers from any of these functions. Try something like this:

```
Block Keywords::parseBlock(TiXmlElement* element)
{
    double x1 = atoi(element->Attribute("left"));
    double y1 = atoi(element->Attribute("top"));
    double x2 = atoi(element->Attribute("right"));
    double y2 = atoi(element->Attribute("bottom"));
    double width = abs(x2 - x1);
    int bid = atoi(element->Attribute("id"));

    vector<LineElement> lines;
    for (TiXmlElement* sub = element->FirstChildElement("line"); sub; sub = sub->NextSiblingElement("line"))
        lines.push_back(parseLine(sub));

    return Block(y2, x2, y1, x1, bid, width, lines);
}

LineElement Keywords::parseLine(TiXmlElement* element)
{
    double x1 = atoi(element->Attribute("left"));
    double y1 = atof(element->Attribute("top"));
    double x2 = atoi(element->Attribute("right"));
    double y2 = atoi(element->Attribute("bottom"));
    int bid = atoi(element->Attribute("id"));

    vector<Element> words;
    for (TiXmlElement* sub = element->FirstChildElement("word"); sub; sub = sub->NextSiblingElement("word"))
        words.push_back(parseWord(sub));

    return LineElement(y2, x2, y1, x1, bid, words);
}

Element Keywords::parseWord(TiXmlElement* element)
{
    string w = element->Attribute("value");
    double x1 = atoi(element->Attribute("left"));
    double y1 = atoi(element->Attribute("top"));
    double x2 = atoi(element->Attribute("right"));
    double y2 = atoi(element->Attribute("bottom"));
    int bid = atoi(element->Attribute("id"));

    vector<Letter> chars;

    for (TiXmlElement* sub = element->FirstChildElement("char"); sub; sub = sub->NextSiblingElement("char"))
        chars.push_back(parseChar(sub));

    return Element(w, y1, x1, y2, x2, -1, bid, chars);
}

Letter Keywords::parseChar(TiXmlElement* element)
{
    string w = element->Attribute("value");
    double x1 = atoi(element->Attribute("left"));
    double y1 = atoi(element->Attribute("top"));
    double x2 = atoi(element->Attribute("right"));
    double y2 = atoi(element->Attribute("bottom"));
    int bid = atoi(element->Attribute("id"));
    return Letter(w, y1, x1, y2, x2, bid);
}
```

The only reason I left the arguments as pointers is that's what your `TiXmlElement`'s `FirstChildElement()` and `NextSiblingElement()` functions return. Normally, I would make them references (`TiXmlElement &element`) instead, which is even safer, since you can't pass `NULL`.

If you really need to avoid the copying for performance reasons, and your compiler isn't smart enough to do that automatically, you can use [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer#C.2B.2B_smart_pointers), which are reference counted, so you don't need to need to worry about `delete`ing them.

```
std::shared_pointer<Block> Keywords::parseBlock(TiXmlElement* element)
{
    double x1 = atoi(element->Attribute("left"));
    double y1 = atoi(element->Attribute("top"));
    double x2 = atoi(element->Attribute("right"));
    double y2 = atoi(element->Attribute("bottom"));
    double width = abs(x2 - x1);
    int bid = atoi(element->Attribute("id"));

    vector<std::shared_pointer<LineElement> > lines;
    for (TiXmlElement* sub = element->FirstChildElement("line"); sub; sub = sub->NextSiblingElement("line"))
        lines.push_back(parseLine(sub));

    return std::shared_pointer<Block>(new Block(y2, x2, y1, x1, bid, width, lines));
}

// etc.
```

Comment: Easiest way, yes! But if creating/copying these classes is expensive, smart pointers give a better 'java equivalent',

Comment: "No reason"? Seems like you've never worked with big XML documents ;)

Comment: @g-makulik It seems you're forgetting about move semantics and NRVO.

Comment: if performance was an issue you wouldn't use XML in the first place.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I actually followed changed return value to just objects. I am testing it now. And I wanted to know why did you say to stop treating c++ like java.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Yes, this is even further considerations for these cases, but applies particularly to C++11 or even some template meta programming tricks (boost?).

Comment: @HaniGoc In Java, the only way to create object is with `new`. In C++, `new` is something you should only use if you have no other options.

Comment: @g-makulik Move semantics were introduced in C++11 indeed, but NRVO is a fairly old concept.

Comment: @Brendan Long Thank you for your help I actually Used the shared_pointer and i was able to solve the problem

Answer (score -1):

You don't generally "return" pointers. You can pass a pointer into the function as a parameter, and assign a value to it in your function. Since a pointer is a memory location, this value will remain in the pointer when your function returns. You can then do any memory management after you have used the pointer for what you want.

Comment: There's nothing unusual about returning a pointer. I see no advantage to your method, it just makes things more complicated.

Comment: Must just be a religious thing on who taught me, I suppose. Always get confused about who "owns" the memory when returning pointers, and thusly, who is responsible for cleanup.